# Foreign Key with wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a table (multisite network) where I use blog_id as one of the columns which is also needed on some of my custom php functions. Until now, I haven't used FK which should be appropriate for my tables.

So, can I FK to wordpress `wp_blogs` table? if yes, if ever I delete that blog will it also delete the entries on my other tables that references `wp_blogs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE wp_blogs (blog_id INT NOT NULL...)
    FOREIGN KEY (blog_id)
    REFERENCES wp_options(blog_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

If you created a table like above then every time when `blog_id` will remove from `wp_options` then all rows from `wp_blogs` will remove too.

When you remove rows from `wp_blogs` then no rows won't remove from `wp_options`

Read about `ON DELETE CASCADE` in MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: I will create a new table for that then references it to wp_options? since wp_blogs is automatically created by wordpress when installing it at multisite network.

Comment: I believed in You all this time :-)